# i push a local index.html to repository but index.html file is empty

Tags: html, git

I made a local "index.html" on sublime text and the code is as following:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> hello world </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> hello world </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I saved this file in a local repository on my computer and then used git push through cmd to upload it on my git. The parent folder does upload and inside the folder i do see the file index.html but this file is empty. I had to copy paste the above code inside index.html file to complete the small project. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you add the file to staging area using `git add .` and commit it using `git commit -m "your msg"`?

Comment: You forgot to commit

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to commit.

**Commit** change the state of your local git. Then, **push** allows to put all your local commits on an other git repository.

No commit = Nothing to push.